# How do I store/print userid/username after user logged in?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to store userid in a variable after the users logged in and I am not sure how to do that. I used `getpass.getuser()`, but it gives me the username from my computer system. Does session work in tkinter? Can somebody give me an idea how should I approach this?
The user id is increased automatically for new user

```
class data:
    def checks(name, password):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('login.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        if cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ? AND password = ?', (name, password)):
            if cur.fetchone():
                window.destroy()
                login_backend.back()
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo('error', 'Username and password is wrong')
def login_student(self):
          if len(self.namee.get()) == 0 or len(self.password1e.get()) == 0:
                     messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", "Mandatory Field is empty")
          else:
            data.checks(self.namee_text.get(), self.password1e_text.get())
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. *How* did the user log in? Can you share the code that's responsible for the user logging in?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get a password and user name on the command line? If so, the secure way to do this is with getpass.getpass(). This will prompt the user. getpass.getuser(), as you discovered, is for the system user.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html

You don't want to print the password on the command line because of the security risk. Generally, you want to consume the sensitive credentials only as long as needed to access the resource.

Comment: not in the command line i want to get username after loging in to tkinter app and use that id to show his data later on